# Windows Explorer Shell-Extension: Column-Handler to Display Shortcut (.LNK) and Bookmark (.URL) Targets

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, shortcuts, shell-extensions

I am looking for a Windows XP Explorer shell-extension that will install a column-handler to display the targets of shortcuts and bookmarks (ie `.LNK` and `.URL` files).

(Windows 7 has a built-in column called *Link Target* that shows this—too bad they didn’t include a folder-size column, [even in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/490378/does-windows-8-explorer-have-a-foldersize-column-or-restore-the-column-handler). `ಠ_ಠ`)

Comment: Apparently Microsoft finally got around to adding a URL column to *Windows 7* that displays the destination of bookmarks (URL files), but not for local shortcuts (LNK files). Sigh.

Comment: Link Target column - superb!

Comment: Yup, the `Link Target` column does indeed show the destination of shortcuts. I recall adding *every* column back when I tested this, so I don’t know how I missed that. ಠ_ఠ

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this Shell Toy - you can also play with the source code.

[Shell Column Ex](http://free-sk.t-com.hr/T800/software/ShellColumnEx.htm)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Even better! Nice find.

Answer (score 0):

The other day while researching the Bags format, I found MiTeC’s [Windows File Analyzer](http://www.mitec.cz/wfa.html). It can let you explore various proprietary Windows filetypes including shortcuts. I’m selecting this as the answer because while xplorer² does have this functionality, it is only available in the paid version, not the free one. Windows File Analyzer on the other hand is completely freeware.