# Does Windows 8 Explorer have a FolderSize column (or restore the column-handler API)?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, shell-extensions

One of the biggest [complaints](http://foldersize.blogspot.ca/) about Windows Vista (and 7) was that it removed the API that allows developers to create column-handlers, and as such, useful programs like [Folder Size](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/) can [no longer function](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net/vistasucks.html).

It seems that a lot of people reported the “bug” and complained, but as yet, no update has been released to provide support for column-handling shell-extensions. I know it’s a long-shot, but has Microsoft finally listened to users and either restored the ability to add column-handlers so that Folder Size can function again, or at least added a built-in column to display folder (and sub-folder) sizes?

To be clear, I am not interested in general size of any individual folder (the *Properties* dialog works fine for that), the goal is to have visual access to *all* folders in a directory and be able to sort them by size.

Comment: It seems like this should go on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Betting they have not and will do anything about this issue. Alternate file browser is the solution most will turn to.

Comment: @Ace, it is not about programming, just asking about whether Windows 8 supports shell-extensions with column-handlers and/or if it (*finally*) has a folder-size column.

Comment: @Moab, unfortunately, I actually *like* Explorer. `:-o` I’ve tried various other shells and have never really liked them; they were either too cluttered, too limited, or flat out flaky/unstable. Explorer (at least so far) seems to strike the right balance—for the most part. Go figure.

Comment: I just checked and it doesn't appear to be built in. Still.

Comment: *> I just checked and it doesn't appear to be built in. Still.*   (Big) \*sigh\*. I don’t understand the argument that it would trash the drive while enumerating if it is off by default. ☹

Comment: Have you tried Q-dir?

Comment: @Moab, Yes.​​​​

Comment: Hmm, interestingly enough, a couple of hours after posting this question, I got a notification of a new post by someone at an MS Community [thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_vista-files/display-folder-sizes-in-windows-explorer/2a687649-c233-4553-a1a8-4f3de6ab5cba) about this issue. Unfortunately it was just yet another person nagging.

Comment: I don't know if this would be related, but if a folder is in the recycle bin, you can see foldersize as a sortable option...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well no; unfortunately Windows 8 Explorer neither has a folder-size column built-in, nor supports shell-extensions like *Folder Size*. Moreover, even shell-extensions like Space Dolphin’s Size (which shows a tree of the sizes of all sub-directories of a folder in a *Properties* dialog tab) don’t work, or rather *remain not working* as they were broken in Vista.

Unfortunately to see the sizes of subfolders, users will have to continue to use external, third-party tools like [WinDirStat](http://windirstat.info/) and [SequoiaView](http://w3.win.tue.nl/nl/onderzoek/onderzoek_informatica/visualization/sequoiaview/) which is just not the same thing because at the very least, they do not let you see the folder sizes right there in Explorer and sort them (technically, some do have a folder-list view which approximates Explorer, but that is still just a work-around and not the same as an actual shell-extension).

Comment: Sadly, even the [Space Dolphin shell-extension](http://www.pcworld.com/product/946740/folder-size-shell-extension.html) that adds a tab to the *Properties* dialog to show the sizes of sub-directories does not work in Vista+ with no built-in alternative. `ಠ╭╮ಠ`

Answer (score 7):

This isn't a direct answer to the question, but possibly makes it slightly easier:

http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2012/05/windows-7-tip-quickly-find-the-folder-size-in-the-folder-tooltip-in-windows-explorer/

Be aware that it does take a while for large folders and gives estimates in some cases.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Size information in tooltips is available in all versions of Windows, but unfortunately, not only does it require manually maneuvering the cursor over each and every item separately and waiting a second or two for the tooltip delay, but it does not allow for sorting items which is pretty essential, otherwise you may as well just access the individual folder’s *Properties* dialog instead of bothering with tooltips.

Comment: Yeah, it's not exactly an optimal solution, just thought I'd offer it up as no-one answered yet.

Comment: It’s not a matter of being optimal, unfortunately it’s not a solution at all. @nhinkle actually *did* provide an answer (as a comment) as to it (still) not being built-in. Nobody commented on whether shell-extensions work, but I would be quite surprised if the do.

Answer (score 6):

I added a reference to the syntech's answer, but he has ignored it.
I propose the [Folder Size](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html) freeware tool.

I like it better than what syntech has proposed, because this tool provides more accurate results, works faster and does not have such a cluttered interface. The latest version can list system and backup folders and reveal better disk usage report than Windows Explorer. While Windows Explorer reported 98GB used on my SSD this tool reported that actually 116 GB were used. Give it a try.
[image]

Comment: I ignored nothing; [your edit was reviewed and rejected](http://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/213559) by other users for being too minor. Your new post is better, but not actually an answer to the question that was asked. I did *not* ask “how can I see folder sizes in Windows 8”? That’s already a well documented question with many answers (including the one you suggested). The question I *actually* asked was whether Windows 8 had a **built-in** folder-size column or if it re-enabled the IColumnProvider interface that FolderSize used. I only mentioned the others as non-ideal workarounds.

Comment: Also, Folder Size is a commercial product which may have led them to reject your edit—especially since you mentioned Mind Gems in 60% of your posts. (Plus, it doesn’t have a tree-map view like the others I mentioned.) Regardless, your reasoning for its use is welcome, though since it’s not actually an answer, it should be a comment, but you don’t have enough rep to post comments yet, so you—or someone else—will need to flag it to have a moderator convert it. For the record, the [original FolderSize](http://foldersize.sourceforge.net) now includes a “kludgey” workaround to support Vista and up.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. To answer your question: There is no such information and better not be unless it is for a different file system.

Why? Pretty simple. 

This information is not available in the file system and should be collected every time - it adds extra load to your storage. That is why I hated the shell extension that you proposed.
1. It makes my system veeery slow
2. It damages my drives by performing extra operations
I prefer the solution that I provide as it add a "Scan with Folder Size" context menu inside Windows Explorer that I use whenever I need it. It is better.

Comment: Yes Folder Size has a PRO version, but most of the important features are available in the FREE version - listing all the file and folder sizes, largest files and folders reports etc. - the things you need for a good disk cleanup.

Comment: `There is no such information` Yes, sadly that is indeed the answer which I already said. `This information is not available in the file system and should be collected every time` Yes, that too is already well known. `It adds extra load to your storage.` Huh? `That is why I hated the shell extension that you proposed. It makes my system veeery slow` Then you shouldn’t have added the column to every folder/root directory. The column is not enabled by default, so it has ZERO impact until you actually enable it, and even then, it uses a cache to reduce impact.

Comment: I do not think you are right. That shell extension installs a service that constantly updates its information on every file operation - an IO hook which is an overkill for such information IMHO.

Comment: `It damages my drives by performing extra operations` If your drive is too old or sick, any drive activity would be risky. `I prefer the solution that I provide as it add a "Scan with Folder Size" context menu inside Explorer that I use whenever I need it.` Sure, and a lot of people are happy with that, but it’s *not* the same as having the size right there in Explorer itself. `Folder Size has a PRO version, but most of the important features are available in the FREE version` True, but 60% of your posts promote Mind Gems, so it seems like [marketing](http://superuser.com/help/behavior).

Comment: `I do not think you are right. That shell extension installs a service that constantly updates its information on every file operation - an IO hook which is an overkill for such information IMHO.` Yes it does so to keep up to date with the occasional *write*, but it does not have a detrimental impact on most systems *because of its cache*. `The FREE version [has most of] the things you need for a good disk cleanup.` Except for a tree-map view which is the most useful piece of information for disk cleanup.

Comment: Syntech I am not arguing with you ... I am just pointing things out with arguments to backup my thesis. Its a matter of personal preference. It is always nice to have more alternatives.

Peace ;)

Comment: No worries; I’m not arguing either, I’m just explaining to clear up the confusion. In any case, Folder Size doesn’t answer this question. If you like Folder Size and want to suggest it, feel free to mention it in some of the [many existing questions](http://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asuperuser.com+windows+folder+size) to which it *does* apply.

Comment: @SarahWilliams +1 the tool helped me what i was looking for..it lists the folders in a new tab and shows the size of each folder while navigating through normal windows explorer..i m just using the free version n it has the most features i want..

Answer (score 1):

I was going to answer by pointing out that while the original Folder Size did not work for some time in Vista and up, it now works by creating a separate window that does track folder sizes.  So while it is not in a column inside the existing Explorer window, it does float next to it, and the separate window can be sorted by size.

However, I see that this is pointed out by @Synetech in one of his comments.  I agree with him that it is "kludgey".

That said, in case others do not peruse the comments as closely as I did, I'll leave this as a possible answer, although it's not strictly speaking an actual "answer" to the original question.  (Also, I can't post comments yet.)

Someone answered with the name of a third party app.  I agree with @Synetech that this doesn't answer the question, which was whether Microsoft had relaxed its restriction on creating columns in explorer or if there was any software that managed to do so.  (I also agree with @Synetech's comment that most of the answerer's posts across this site refer to the same software maker, so perhaps there is a bias or agenda here.)

That said, in the interests of fairness and because the third party app posted is a *pay* app, here are some free alternatives:

- WinDirStat (https://windirstat.info/)
- TreeSizeFree (http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/)
- http://www.folder-size-explorer.com/

Enjoy.

Editing further in 2020: Double Explorer, which is an open source Norton-Commander-like explorer, doesn't provide a column for directory sizes, but if you space bar to select, will quite quickly calculate its size. Very handy.